# Resizing uploaded elFinder images

Tags: php, symfony, elfinder

I want a different image resize during upload, instead of 200x100. However, I can not find any related files to make this adjustment.

After some search I've seen multiple people tell others to look into the *connector.php*. In this file I need to pass something following along these lines:

```
$opts = array(
            'bind' => array(
                'upload resize' => array($this, 'myResize')
            ),
            'roots' => array(
                array(...)
            )
        );

/**
     * Upload/resize callback catcher, resizes image to 320x240px/240x320px respectively, keeps ratio
     *
     * @param  string   $cmd       command name
     * @param  array    $result    command result
     * @param  array    $args      command arguments from client
     * @param  object   $elfinder  elFinder instance
     * @return true     Forces elFinder to sync all events
     * */
    public function myResize($cmd, $result, $args, $elfinder) {
        $files = $result['added'];
        foreach ($files as $file) {
            $arg = array(
                'target' => $file['hash'],
                'width' => 320,
                'height' => 320,
                'x' => 0,
                'y' => 0,
                'mode' => 'propresize',
                'degree' => 0
            );
            $elfinder->exec('resize', $arg);
        }

        return true;
    }
```

My big question is:

Where do I place this function? I am using the (FM)ElfinderBundle for Symfony2.

Answer (score 1):

There are two ways for solve this question.

1. place your function (myResize) in connector.php:

   ```
   public function myResze($cmd, $result, $args, $elfinder)
   {
     //other code
   }
   ```

then set 'bind' to:

```
'bind' => array(
    'upload resize' => 'myResize');
```

2. define your class in connector.php and get an instance for using in 'bind'. example :

```
    class className
    {
       // other code

       public function myResize($cmd, $result, $args, $elfinder)
       {
         // other code
       }
    }
```

after create an object from this class :

```
$obj = new className();
```

then set 'bind' to this :

```
'bind' => array(
    'upload resize' => array($obj, 'myResize'));
```

this example is useful for you : https://github.com/Studio-42/elFinder/wiki/Logging

Comment: You cannot put public function in connector.php because it will be out of class